# SQL Most effective way to store every word in a document separately

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, search, document

Here's my situation (or **see TLDR at bottom**): I'm trying to make a system that will search for user entered words through several documents and return the documents that contain those words. The user(s) will be searching through thousands of documents, each of which will be 10 - 100+ pages long, and stored on a webserver.

The solution I have right now is to store each unique word in a table with an ID (only maybe 120 000 relevant words in the English language), and then in a separate table store the word id, the document it is in, and the number of times it appears in that document.

E.g: Document foo's text is

> abc abc def

and document bar's text is

> abc def ghi

Documents table will have

**id**  |  **name**

```
1 'foo'
2 'bar'
```

Words table:

**id** | **word**

```
1 'abc'
2 'def'
3 'ghi'
```

Word Document table:

**word id** | **doc id** | **occurrences**

```
1        1        2
1        2        1
2        1        1
2        2        1
3        2        1
```

As you can see when you have thousands of documents and each has thousands of unique words, the Word Document tables blows up very quickly and takes way too long to search through.

**TL;DR My question is this:**

How can I store searchable data from large documents in an SQL database, while retaining the ability to use my own search algorithm (I am aware SQL has one built in for .docs and pdfs) based on custom factors (like occurrence, as well as others) without having an outright massive table for all the entries linking each word to a document and its properties in that document?

Sorry for the long read and thanks for any help!

Comment: If full-text search doesn't solve all of your problems, maybe a relational database isn't the solution you're after anyway...

Comment: As I said, I would like to have full control over the search algorithm, and prioritize certain words over others based on an arbitrary feature set for each word.

Comment: The content index guys actually store the location of each word in the document (so you can tell if words are nearby each other, find phrases, etc.), not just the number of occurrences.

Comment: This is a problem better suited for `nosql`  In particular redis

Comment: Are you required to use SQL?

Comment: At the moment, NOSQL is not an option (I have considered it, but my situation does not allow for it). I have to use MSSQL or MySQL and ASP.net

Comment: i think your structure is correct.  it will be about the indexing

Comment: Agree with Randy then.  Set up benchmarks with no indexes and then add index, rerun, etc.  I have a similar issue with a MySQL db and I was surprised which indexes affected performance.

Comment: @Gabe Occurrences was just an example, I might store lots of other features later on as well.

Comment: Have you looked into [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/)?

Comment: @Roman Fair warning. You REALLY want to use the pre-built solution. Either SQL Server full-text searching or something like Lucene. You will lose many, many days of your life that you could spend on more productive things if you try to make your own search engine. Realize that Google is very valuable for a reason, it's not something you can duplicate easily.

Comment: @JeffDavis From what I can tell, SQL Server uses a very similar solution to my own, however gives me less control over how the search is carried out and how results are organized. As for something like Lucene, I am definitely looking into its implementation. I am well aware of the value and complexity behind Google, and although their degree of result relevancy is remarkable, I have no plans of attempting to duplicating it with my own code.

Comment: hi @Roman has any of these answers been helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When an answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than building your own search engine using SQL Server, have you considered using a C# .net implementation of the lucene search api's? Have a look at https://github.com/apache/lucene.net

Comment: It looks like my best bet is to use Lucene. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I would piggy back on the existing solution of SQL Server (full text indexing). They have integrated a nice indexing engine which optimises considerably better than your own code probably could do (or the developers at Microsoft are lazy or they just got a dime to build it :-)

Please see [SQL server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306.aspx) text indexing background. You could query views such as sys.fulltext_index_fragments or use stored procedures.

Ofcourse, piggy backing on an existing solution has some draw backs:

1. You need to have a license for the solution.
2. When your needs can no longer be served, you will have to program it all yourself.

But if you allow SQL Server to do the indexing, you could more easily and with less time build your own solution.

Answer (score -3):

Your question strikes me as being naive. In the first place... you are begging the question. You are giving a flawed solution to your own problem... and then explaining why it can't work. Your question would be much better if you simply described what your objective is... and then got out of the way so that people smarter than you could tell you **HOW** to accomplish that objective.

Just off hand... the database sounds like a really dumb idea to me. People have been grepping text with command line tools in UNIX-like environments for a long time. Either something already exists that will solve your problem or else a decent perl script will "fake" it for you-- depending on your real world constraints, of course.

Depending on what your problem actually is, I suspect that this could get into some really interesting computer science questions-- indexing, Bayesian filtering, and who knows what else. I suspect, however, that you're making a very basic task more complicated than it needs to be.

**TL;DR My answer is this:**

** Why wouldn't you just write a script to go through a directory... and then use regexes to count the occurences of the word in each file that is found there?

Comment: So you're saying there is no need to preprocess tens of thousands of documents to make subsequent searches faster?  The solution is to just do a search through all of the files each time?  Even if the system needs to do lots of searches quickly?

Comment: That may be a significant problem there, mbeckish. The problem with breaking the documents down into individual words in a database is that it does not allow you to search for phrases or patterns. If speed is an issue, you can always cache your search results so that the most commonly used searches aren't being redone.

Comment: If you store the correct index data per word, you could also search for phrases, ans others have mentioned above.

Comment: This solution will be deployed on a webserver. My sincerest apologies, I forgot to clarify that in the original post. There will be million of documents simultaneously being accessed by thousands of users. I can't imagine the kind of hard server-side storage I would require to search quickly. And the reason I provided my flawed solution is in an attempt to help people understand the objective in case I wasn't clear enough.